# Name of a function is 'not avalable' inside the function itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Why the function's name is 'not available' in the VS Code debug console even though I could use it in the assignment?

[image]

Comment: V8 does some optimizations, if you really want it, use console inside to get too.

Comment: `void function foo ()` ? I don't think that does what you expect... It makes the function a function expression and discards the value.

Comment: Uh, I don't think `void function foo ()` is valid Javascript...

Comment: It is valid, I'll post an answer

Comment: If it's valid, then why does JSlint say `Error : Unexpected 'void'.` ?

Comment: Well, obviously, because it is a lint error. It just says that it is not a best practice and better not to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read more about [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void).

> The void operator evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined.

So, in your case, what it means is:

- Take a function expression `function foo() { ... }`
- Evaluate it and return nothing

```js
void function test() {
  console.log('boo!');
  // expected output: "boo!"
}();

try {
  test();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  // expected output: ReferenceError: test is not defined
}
```

If you want to make it work, discard the `void`:

```
function foo() {
  const x = foo;
}
```

Though, I assume that you wanted to specify a return type for the function. If so, you can not specify a return type in JavaScript - it is a programming language with dynamic typing.

Though, with TypeScript, you could write:

```
function foo(): void {
  const x = foo;
}
```

Comment: But the same snippet of code works in Chrome's DevTools and the debugger sees the function name just as well as the local variable. (https://imgur.com/a/UoBUpvm)

Comment: Also the trick with void is just an alternative to a self-invoking function syntax. I don't use the name anywhere else in the code. The code on the picture is all the code there is. I could just as easily define a 'normal' function and call it later with its name still not being available (to the VS Code debugger) inside itself.

Comment: Never seen IIFE with void syntax, better to use `(function foo() {})()` syntax for that, not the void operator.